# Merging Multiple Text File Data, but Specific Lines to Another

Tags: script, batch-file, csv, merge

I have several Textfiles with a header of no interest and some relevant data.
I want a new file with all the important data:

**Example**:

**File1 has text:**

```
Created on 02.02.2016
Country: Chile
Figure of Station: CAL
Frequency: 220 Hz
Messuring: 15 hours
```

**File2 has text:**

```
Created on 02.02.2016
Country: Chile
Figure of Station: GUA
Frequency: 220 Hz
Messuring: 14 hours
```

*I would like to have new csv with all important data looking like:*

```
CAL 220 Hz 15 hours
GUA 220 Hz 14 hours
```

Is it possible to do something like this with a batch file?

I know about copy `.csv` all `.txt` but this doesn't work here.

Here is a batch script I have as well.

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist result.csv del result.csv
for %%f in (*.txt) do (
    set i=0
    for /F "delims=" %%l in (%%f) do (
        set /A i+=1
        set line!i!=%%l
    )
    echo %%f, !line1!, !line2!, !line3!, !line4!, !line5!, >> result.csv
)
```

Comment: Yes, it is possible, however please note that [SU] is not a script writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (including any scripts you are using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Hello, yes I understand. I m pretty clueless with cmd commands. My programming "skills" are limited to Matlab and GMT and even there give me a hard time! My script idea looks like this. My main problem seems now it copies everything but I just want the relevant part of my stations i measured

Comment: It's a start I suppose. I might look at it tomorrow if I have time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### I want a new file with all the important data

I've modified your batch file to produce the results you want.

Use the following batch file (test.cmd):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
if exist result.csv del result.csv
for %%f in (file*.txt) do (
  set _line=
  rem we don't need the first 2 lines so skip them
  rem we only need the data after the : 
  rem so use : as the delimeter and get the rest of the tokens after the delimeter 
  for /f "skip=2 tokens=2* delims=:" %%l in (%%f) do (
    set _value=%%l
    rem strip off the space that is after the : and build up the output line
    set _line=!_line!!_value:~1! 
    )
  rem write the output line to the file
  echo !_line! >> result.csv
  )
endlocal
```

Notes:

- Change `file*.txt` to match your text files.

Example usage:

```
F:\test>type file*.txt

file1.txt


Created on 02.02.2016
Country: Chile
Figure of Station: CAL
Frequency: 220 Hz
Messuring: 15 hours
file2.txt


Created on 02.02.2016
Country: Chile
Figure of Station: GUA
Frequency: 220 Hz
Messuring: 14 hours
F:\test>test

F:\test>type result.csv
CAL 220 Hz 15 hours
GUA 220 Hz 14 hours

F:\test>
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [for](http://ss64.com/nt/for2.html) - Conditionally perform a command on several files.
- [for /f](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html) - Loop command against the results of another command.
- [variables](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-substring.html) - Extract part of a variable (substring).

Comment: First of all. Thanks very much it does the trick. Now a question for the curious: Skip can be used for starting lines is there also a command where it stops at a certain point? I only found the possibility do define it by lines. http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: @Loomdock You have to add your own logic to stop the loop. There are many ways to do that depending on the specific circumstances. Basically you use `goto label` to break out of `for` loops.